# Enunciate validation of Jersey API fails with @POST @FormParam + String data

Tags: jersey, enunciate

I'm evaluating enunciate to document our REST APIs and I'm having an issue with the validation step:

```
Validation result has errors.
my.java: error: [core] An entity parameter must be of type MultivaluedMap<String, String> if there is another parameter annotated with @FormParam.
                            @FormParam("my-param") String myParam, String data)
```

This construct of accepting the POST data as a String entity in addition to @FormParam bindings is supported by Jersey, so not sure why enunciate is choking on it? Is this not JAX-RS compliant?

This is a really useful to capture the full post data for auditing purposes if something went wrong. Is there a way to configure enunciate to ignore this argument?

If not, is there some other way to capture the post data in a way that would keep enunciate happy? I'm reluctant to go to MultivaluedMap as the stringification process may not result in exactly the String which was passed in...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the validation checks Enunciate performs are outdated. You might consider requesting a change by [submitting a JIRA issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ENUNCIATE).

One thing you could try as a workaround is to create your own custom parameter annotation and configure Enunciate consider it as a custom resource parameter.

```
 <enunciate>
   ...
   <services>
     <rest>
       <custom-resource-parameter-annotation qualifiedName="org.myco.CustomResourceParam"/>
     </rest>
   </services>
   ...
 </enunciate>
```

However, if the purpose of the parameter is for auditing, I'd really recommend using a [Jersey filter](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html). That way you don't litter your API code with auditing concerns.